# Listing comments by author else not working

Tags: wordpress, comments, author, codex

I have a code that listing comments by author. I use it in author.php. It list comments perfectly but if the author has no comments it shows other authors comment links.

**the code**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'user_id' => get_the_author_meta('ID'),
    'number' => 5, // how many comments to retrieve
    'status' => 'approve'
    );

$comments = get_comments( $args );

if ( $comments )
{

    foreach ( $comments as $c )
    {
    $output.= '<li">';
    $output.= '<a href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'">';
    $output.= get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);

    $output.= "</a></li>\n";
    }
    echo $output;
} else { echo "There is no comment yet.";}
?>
```

i want to see here if author has no comment: **else { echo "There is no comment yet.";}**

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Are you sure the get_the_author_meta('ID') function returns the correct value?

Comment: i think it is. if not it will not work. i only have error if user has no comment.

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed it by changing:** `'user_id' => get_the_author_meta('ID'),`

**i changed it as:**    `'author_email' =>  $curauth->user_email,`